# Write values of Python dictionary back to file

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I extracted information from two XML files into 2 dictionaries because I wanted to compare these files and change information in one of them.

These are my dictionaries:

source dictionary:

```
d_source={'123': 'description_1', '456': 'description_2'}
```

target dictionary:

```
d_target={'123': '\n', '456': 'description_2'}
```

This is my replacement code:

```
for i in d_source:
    for j in d_target:
        if d_target[j]=='\n':
            d_target[j]=d_source[i]
print (d_target)
```

d_target is updated to

```
d_target = {'123': 'description_1', '456': 'description_2'}
```

However, my original files from which I extracted the dictionaries remain unchanged. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you expect the Python code to modify the files if you're modifying dictionaries?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking....I am new to Python. I thought I could re-import the dictionary into my file, but don't know how.

Comment: You need to write the dictionary back to the file, there is no link between the dictionary and the file.

Comment: please post your file-io code

Comment: it is usually not helpful to show the entire code. You should paste enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem you observe. You should paste it here, that others don't need to visit an external site. (If scrollbars appear it's probably too much code.)

Comment: Looks to me like your trying to use pipe redirection where "print" is similar to sys.stdout.write(text). if you use print then use a redirector at the command prompt/terminal like so: python.exe myxml_mod.py > output.xml

Comment: By the way, I see your example code users things like file = open(...). While this is legal and will actually work fine, be ware that "file" is a built in type. When you do file=open(...) you are reasigning the file "varible" to a the return value of function open().  Personally to remind me to avoid using file = open(...) I instead use fd = open(...) where fd stands for file descriptor. btw you can also do fd = file('myfile','r')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solutions for you would be:

Let's say you want to print it as a json, it makes sense if you are already using dicts.

```
import json 
output = json.dumps(d_target)

f = open("myfile", 'w')
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

This will print your dict to file myfile as a json.

And if you want it as a xml you can use elementtree module.

Then you could use something like this:

```
from elementtree import ElementTree as ETree
ET = ETree
ET.xml_declaration = "true"
products = ET.Element("products")
properties = ET.Element("properties")
products.append(properties)
products.attrib["xmlns"] = "http://schema.example.com/product_data_1.0"
update = ET.Element("update")
delete = ET.Element("delete")
products.append(delete)
products.append(update)
```

This is just an example to see how it is done and this would create something like:

```
 <products xmlns="http://schema.example.com/product_data_1.0">
      <properties />
      <delete />
      <update />
 </products>
```

And to print this xml to file again:

```
output = ET.tostring(products, "utf-8")
f = open("xml", 'w')
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

Comment: JSON is simple. XML is usually a bit harder, since there is no one-to-one mapping. But in general the approach is correct. Deserialize, change, then serialize.

Comment: Great idea! But unfortunately I need an XML output, otherwise I cannot re-import the file into my software :/.

Answer (score 0):

Your replacement code (in your example) can be replaced by the `.update()` method on a `dict`.

```
d_target.update(d_source)
```

I'm not sure how you want to persist the `dict` but using the `json` module is one option. Otherwise if you wanted an updated XML file, you'll have to look at modifying attributes in the nodes, and writing the result of "somelibraryhere".tostring()'s (or similar) method.